# How to organize Istio rate limiting policy configuration

Tags: istio

Let me present a usecase for various independant teams deploying to a single cluster
Team A is responsible for servics A1, A2, A3
Team B is responsible for servics B1, B2, B3

They both intend to apply custom Rate Limiting to their services. My Question is:

Should/Could they both define completely different config(consisting of the following 5 yalm spec) or is part of it common? At the very least, I'm guessing the "quota instance" could be shared while the rest could be different.

From the istio site ( https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/#rate-limits ) , the config is split into

- Client Side

  - QuotaSpec defines quota name and amount that the client should request.
  - QuotaSpecBinding conditionally associates QuotaSpec with one or more services.
- Mixer Side

  - quota instance defines how quota is dimensioned by Mixer.
  - memquota handler defines memquota adapter configuration.
  - quota rule defines when quota instance is dispatched to t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as im concerned you should be able to do that.

You should start with creating a single redis handler and a simple rule that limits based on a single dimension and try to apply that to services from team A and create a similar rule that applies to services B.

> Should/Could they both define completely different config(consisting of the following 5 yalm spec) or is part of it common?
>
> **Handler** - a single one, to connect to Redis or to keep all the rate limiting info in one place
>
> **Instance** - This can be single, or there can be 2 - depending on usecase
>
> **QuotaSpec** - as many as instances defined
>
> **QuotaSpecBinding** - two or even more
>
> **Rule** - Depends on usecase, You probably start with one, but eventually may use two or more

If You want to rate limit based on same dimensions, one shared instance is enough.

Single instance is possible, unless the teams want to use different dimensions,then obviously You would need two seperate quota instances.

I found something like [namespace tenancy](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/deployment-models/#namespace-tenancy) on istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/), i think if You would like, You could create a 2 seperate namespaces for both, team A and team B.